# UICollectionView in UIScrollView -> Scroll Order

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` inside a `UIScrollView`.

My plan is, if the `UICollectionView` reached the Top or Bottom the
outer ScrollView gets the scroll gestures. If the outer
ScrollView reached the Top or the Bottom, the CollectionView gets
the gestures.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here is my Solution in some words:

1. -Observe the contentOffset of both ScrollViews
2. -Check when the inner scrollView reach the top or bottom
3. -Disable the Scroll from the inner Scrollview
4. -Enable the Scroll from the outer Scrollview
5. -Check when the outer scrollView reach the top or bottom
6. -Disable the Scroll from the outer Scrollview
7. -Enable the Scroll from the inner Scrollview

very simple!
Observe the contentOffset like this:

```
[self.scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

this methode get called:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"]) {

        } else {

        }
    }
```