# How to implement non-scrollable UICollectionView inside UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

In shorts, my desired screen layout is basically a user profile (iOS 7 + Xcode 5). I used UIScrollView as the top level view. *The reason is that **I want all its subviews to scroll** (user info view - the view with a profile image and some buttons you see on the screen, and the photos collection view - the one with black background) when it is scrolled.*

[image]

The region with black background will show user photos. I'm wondering if I could use a UICollectionView here, or there's a better way to implement it. The UICollectionView in this case shouldn't be able to scroll itself, it just shows all cells, while the scrolling work is handled by the outermost UIScrollView.

I read following posts:

[UICollectionView inside of UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224599/uicollectionview-inside-of-uiscrollview)

[UICollectionView in UIScrollView -> Scroll Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538551/uicollectionview-in-uiscrollview-scroll-order)

[iOS 7 Collection View inside Scroll View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338466/ios-7-collection-view-inside-scroll-view)

Some said it's not possible (or at least, weird) implemeting UICollectionView inside UIScrollView because UIScrollView is UICollectionView's superclass which leads to unexpected behaviour. Some said it should be implemented in another way (but I didn't see a clear suggestion).

Comment: So you're saying you want the orange bar with the “Social Profile” label, and the fuzzy background image, and everything overlaid on the fuzzy background image, to scroll vertically off the top of the screen, and you want the black area to be filled with photos, and for more photos to appear as the screen is scrolled upward?  Do you want the tab bar at the bottom to remain fixed?

Comment: yes you're right, however I would like navigation bars and tab bars remain fixed :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can put a `UICollectionView` inside a `UIScrollView`.  [iOS has fully supported nested scroll views since iOS 3.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html), and `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  For example, check out the App Store app on your iOS device.  The screen scrolls vertically - it's either a `UIScrollView` or a `UITableView` (which is itself a subclass of `UIScrollView`).  And each row of icons scrolls horizontally - each row is a `UICollectionView`.

However, it's not clear why **you** need to put a collection view inside a scroll view.  It sounds like you only want the photos view to scroll, so just make the photos view be a collection view.  Why do you need to put the collection view inside a scroll view?

#### UPDATE

Just use a collection view.  Set the header of section 0 to the profile info view.  You don't need a scroll view.

If you put all the photos in one section, you can set up the header in your storyboard with no code.  If you use multiple sections, you'll need to implement `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` in your delegate and `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` in your data source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason is that I want the entire screen to be scrolled, i.e. the user info view is not docked on the top. It should scroll when I scroll way down to see photos...

Comment: great setup. I found out and implemented this way just an hour ago. Your answer makes me more confident about the good practice. Thanks! :)

Comment: What if you want the header view to be expandable like an accordion. If its set up as a header view for section 0 of the collection view, how to implement the animation of it expanding and collapsing.

Comment: Invalidate the collection view layout after setting the flag that means the header is expanded. When returning the cell for the header, check the flag to determine how to configure the cell.